# @WicketHomePage not found

Tags: maven, spring-boot, wicket

> Blockquote
>
> J have a Eclipse workspace with a maven parent project (parent) and child > >projects (Domain,Web,Win)
>   The parent pom contains the wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>org.SteinKo.ATM</groupId>
      <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>


      <name>Parent</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      
      
      
        <modules>
            <module>Domain</module>
            <module>Web</module>
            <module>Win</module>
        </modules>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      </properties>
      
      <scm>
    <connection>scm:git@github.com:steinKo/ATM.git</connection>
    <url>https://github.com/steinKo/ATM.git</url>
    </scm>

    <parent>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter/wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent -->

        <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId></artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
         
    </parent>
```

> The web projects contains a Wicket pages

```
package steinKo.ATM;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

import steinKo.ATM.presentaion.web.HomePage;

@SpringBootApplication

public class Web {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Web.class).run(args);
    }

    public Class<HomePage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }
}
```

> 

```
package steinKo.ATM.presentaion.web;
import com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.context.scan.WicketHomePage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

import steinKo.ATM.domain.ATM;
import steinKo.ATM.domain.Bank;

@WicketHomePage
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ATM atm;
    private Bank bank;

    public HomePage() {
        bank = new Bank();
        atm = new ATM(bank);
        add(new MenuPanel("menuPanel"));
        add(new ContentPanel("contentPanel", atm));

    }

}
```

> The pom.xml for the web contain dependency to wicket-spring-boot-starter

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>Web</artifactId>



 <parent>
  <groupId>org.SteinKo.ATM</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
   <relativePath />
</parent>


<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
          <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When I execute maven test on parent project I get the message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter:wicket-spring-boot-starter:jar is missing. @ org.SteinKo.ATM:Web:[unknown-version], /Users/stein/Development/ATM/Parent/Web/pom.xml, line 20, column 16
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar is missing. @ org.SteinKo.ATM:Web:[unknown-version], /Users/stein/Development/ATM/Parent/Web/pom.xml, line 28, column 13 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   The project org.SteinKo.ATM:Web:0.0.1 (/Users/stein/Development/ATM/Parent/Web/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter:wicket-spring-boot-starter:jar is missing. @ org.SteinKo.ATM:Web:[unknown-version], /Users/stein/Development/ATM/Parent/Web/pom.xml, line 20, column 16
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar is missing. @ org.SteinKo.ATM:Web:[unknown-version], /Users/stein/Development/ATM/Parent/Web/pom.xml, line 28, column 13
[ERROR]
```

and 
 the
 import com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.context.scan.WicketHomePage; and
 @WicketHomePage is marked red in the has a message "Can not be resolved"

Why?

Comment: You mean you have the compilation error ?

Comment: Seems @soorapadman You are right, there is no import, but lets wait for answer

Answer (score 1):

It look like maven build issue for me `dependencies.dependency.version` not properly loading the dependency of `com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter` from parent . Please build using `mvn clean install` from  `parent` to all the project and fix . Its nothing to do with code .

And more over i'm not sure whether you shared your full `pom` add this Your pom not correct change this

```
 <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId></artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
```

to

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```